# In each case, say whether or not R is a partial order on A. If so, is it a linear order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A= the set of all countries in the world, R={ (x,y)∈ A×A | the population of the country y is at least as large as the population of the country x}.
Originally I had written that:
This relation is reflexive and transitive but not symmetric This is because there are many pairs of (x, y) such that xRy is true but yRx is false. For example, the only way xRy and yRx can both be true is if x is less than or equal to y, and y is less than or equal to x, and thus x = y, making it antisymmetric.

But then I realized that the definition of a linear order is that it is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric. And so now I would say that this relation is in fact a partial order, but how would I know if it is a total/linear order?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A partial order is transitive, reflexive, and antisymmetric. A total/linear order is a partial order where for any elements $a,b$ we have $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Is my original statement about this relation being a partial order correct? I'm still a bit confused about the antisymmetric aspect of it

Comment: It's also not the best defined problem, since the answer depends on if there are any countries with exactly equal populations.

Comment: It looks like your original statement is talking about symmetry, not antisymmetry. You are arguing that it isn't symmetric, and you're definitely right about that. Unfortunately it isn't very relevant to a partial order.

Comment: If I were to say that this is in fact a partial order, since it is transitive, antisymmetric and reflexive, would I be correct?

Comment: As I mentioned before, that depends on if any two countries have exactly equal populations. I'd recommend taking a look at the definition of antisymmetry and thinking about why that makes a difference.

Comment: Assuming that there exists two countries with the same population, I have updated my answer to this:

Comment: This relation is a partial order on A but is not a linear order. This relation is reflexive, transitive and also antisymmetric. However, it is not a linear order because a total/linear order is a partial order where for any elements x, y, we have x ≤ y or y ≤ x. In this case, it is stated that the population of the country y is at least as large as the population of the country x, meaning that there is not a case such that the population of country y would be smaller than the population of country x, making y ≤ x false. Thus, this relation is a partial order on A but not a linear order.

Answer (score 1):

There's one sentence in your question that seems to indicate that you've misunderstood something.  You wrote "For example, the only way $xRy$ and $yRx$ can both be true is if $x$ is less than or equal to $y$, and $y$ is less than or equal to $x$, and thus $x = y$, making it antisymmetric."  But $x$ and $y$ here are *countries*, not *numbers*.  If $xRy$ and $yRx$, then what that means is that (population of $x$) $\le$ (population of $y$) and (population of $y$) $\le$ (population of $x$), and thus $x$ and $y$ have the same population.  But that doesn't mean $x = y$; they could be two different countries that happen to have the same population.  If that were to happen, then $R$ would fail to be antisymmetric, and therefore it wouldn't be a partial order.  But it seems unlikely that there are two countries with exactly the same population.  If no such countries exist, then $R$ is a total order.